# How to use web api on android using javascript, jquery and jsonp?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jsonp, asp.net-web-api

im trying to set up a button in my android program that when pushed gets some information from a web api and displays the result on my screen.

this is the code that does all the work, but i need to put it in my android page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function get_temp(){
var url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/00000000003/conditions/q/';
    url+=$('#lat').val()+','+$('#lon').val()+' .json?callback=?';
    $('#log').html($('#log').html()+url);
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var temp = data['current_observation']['temp_c'];
        $('#out').html($('#shoedata').html()+temp+'<br>');
    });
 }
 //-->
</script>
Latitude <input type="text" name="name" id="lat" />
Longitude <input type="text" name="name" id="lon" />
<input value="Get temperatura" type="button" onclick="get_temp()"/>
<div id='out'>Current temperature: </div>
<div id="log">Log: </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i do this?
what are the steps i should follow to write js code in android? is it any different also for jquery and jsonp?
Thanks!

Comment: One does not write JS code in Android. In Android you going to instantiate a HttpClient that will do a GET or POST and the web server will return the information in JSON

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Friend use below given Links.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

[JSON,XML connecting to web api for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600187/json-xml-connecting-to-web-api-for-android)

> Hope these will help you.